How to create base type for struct in go?
In other languages support inheritance like C++, any derived class is a base class:
class ComparisonOperator{}
class GreaterThan : public ComparisonOperator {...}
class EqualTo: public ComparisonOperator {...}
class LessThan: public ComparisonOperator {...}

So GreaterThan, EqualTo, and LessThan are ComparisonOparator. It is easy to constrain that the input argument operator must be a type of ComparisonOperator:
template <typename T>
void Compare(ComparisonOperator operator, T val1, T val2) bool {
...
}

I am not sure how to achieve same thing in Golang, I am now using implementation like this, the problem is GreaterThan, LessThan, EqualTo are all struct, in CompareInt function, I cannot constrain the argument operator must be either GreaterThan or LessThan or EqualTo.
func CompareInt(operator any, int val1, int val2) bool {
}

type GreaterThan struct {
   ...
}

type LessThan struct {
   ...
}

type EqualTo struct {
 ...
}


Go polymorphism is based on behavioral subtyping with interfaces, note structural with inheritance. Of course for this specific example you could just pass a func that does the comparison, no extra types needed.

You can write Java (or C++) in any language, but for Go it would be idiomatic to use functions for that purpose:
func Compare[T Ordered](x, y T) int
func Less[T Ordered](x, y T) bool
So you would define a type constraint Ordered for your types and then implement Compare and Less for that. Compare[int] could be implemented like that:
package main

import (
    "cmp"
    "fmt"
)

func Compare[T cmp.Ordered](operator func(T, T) bool, val1, val2 T) bool {
    return operator(val1, val2)
}

func Equal[T cmp.Ordered](x, y T) bool {
    return cmp.Compare(x, y) == 0
}

func Greater[T cmp.Ordered](x, y T) bool {
    return cmp.Compare(x, y) > 0
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("1 > 2: %v\n", Compare(Greater, 1, 2))
    fmt.Printf("1 == 2: %v\n", Compare(Equal, 1, 2))
    fmt.Printf("1 < 2: %v\n", Compare(cmp.Less, 1, 2))
}

Try it on the Go playground.

You can define an interface, Compare for example, and use operator Compare instead of operator any. For example:
type Compare interface{
   CompareMethod(val1, val2 int)bool
}

func CompareInt(operator Compare, int val1, int val2) bool {
}

type GreaterThan struct {
   ...
}

func (gt GreaterThan) CompareMethod(va1, val2 int)bool {
    ...
}

type LessThan struct {
   ...
}

type EqualTo struct {
 ...
}

Only a struct which has realized a function func CompareMethod(int,int)bool can be passed as the para operator to function CompareInt.
